# Ubuntu got EPIPE error when using -q flag with grep

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I have a bash script I use to check if certain forever processes are running. The script is basically:

```
#!/bin/bash

processIsRunning=$(forever list | grep -q 'process/index.js')
if [ -n $processIsRunning]; then
    echo 'Processes are running'
else 
    echo 'Processes are not running'
fi
```

I get this error though:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: write EPIPE
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Object.afterWrite (net.js:720:19)
```

If I remove the '-q' flag from my grep command in line 3 then I do not get a pipe error, but instead I get an error about it trying to run the grep result as a command instead of just checking for the length of the output to be greater than 0.
Does anyone know why the -q parameter would cause an EPIPE error?

UPDATE BASED ON COMMENTS:
My mistake, I'm pretty new to bash and was trying to learn how to use if statements. I originally had it directly in the if statement but took it out into a variable because it wasn't working (turns out it was failing because of my lack of spaces, didn't realize they are a requirement in bash). I clearly didn't port it out properly. I'm currently using just grep without -q and then checking the length of the output and that is working well.

Comment: First, `grep -q` doesn't output anything, so trying to capture its output via `$(`...`)` doesn't make sense.  The way to use it is something like `if forever list | grep -q 'process/index.js'; then`

Comment: Second, I can't reproduce the problem - `forever list` completes successfully whether writing to the terminal, a `grep` process without `-q`, a `grep` process with `-q`, a file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
forever list | grep -q 'process/index.js'
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo 'Processes are running'
else 
    echo 'Processes are not running'
fi
```

grep -q says do not write anything to standard output.

$? is used to find the return value of the last executed command.

Comment: `==` is non-standard and shouldn't be used alongside with `[`. You can just use `if forever list | grep -q 'process/index.js'` anyway rather than checking `$?`.

Comment: Point taken and code edited to reflect this. You are also right in saying if forever list | grep -q 'process/index.js' as well.